# Как получить в результате SQL запроса новогоднюю елочку?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Ну да, это несерьезный вопрос, но в последний день уходящего 2020 года, у многих из нас появляется желание проявить немного легкомыслия.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do I print out a Christmas tree with SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65434426) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Comment: Новогодняя ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65434426

Answer (score 6):

Запустите SQL*Plus в xterm или в командном окне Windows 10, и выполните следующий запрос. Получите ёлочку со случайно разбросанными огоньками и, конечно же, в насыщенном цвете.

С Новым Годом всех!

```
set lines 350 pagesize 0
clear screen

select 
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(r,
                'X', chr(27)||'[42m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(32)||'m'||'X'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
            'T',chr(27)||'[43m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(33)||'m'||'T'||chr(27)||'[0m'),
        '@',chr(27)||'[33m'||chr(27)||'[1;'||to_char(31)||'m'||'@'||chr(27)||'[0m')
from ( 
    select lpad(' ',20-e-i)|| 
        case when dbms_random.value < 0.3 then substr(s,1,e*2-3+i*2) 
        else substr(substr(s,1,dbms_random.value(1,e*2-3+i*2-1))||'@'||s,1,e*2-3+i*2) end r
    from ( 
        select rpad('X',40,'X') s,rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ), ( 
            select level i, level+2 hop from dual connect by level<= 4), lateral ( 
                select level e from dual connect by level<=hop) 
                union all 
                select lpad(' ',17)||substr(t,1,3)
        from ( 
            select rpad('X',40,'X') s, rpad('T',40,'T') t from dual ) connect by level<=5)
/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434427) от участника [@Connor McDonald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7367293/connor-mcdonald)</sub>

Comment: wow! красиво! никогда бы не догадался рисовать елку в SQL! :-D

Comment: Ой здорово! Добавьте в основной конкурс пожалуйста.